# Failing to get a download URL from firebase storage(No object exists at the desired reference.)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i have been trying to get the download URL for my images in firebase storage so I can add it to my listview builders "NetworkCatched Images" for each of my items in the list, as you can see from my code below, I first declared a variable at the beginning of my stateful class called "URL" so I could change the value by making it equal to the download URL i get from firebase storage, but it seems like the async function I'm using doesn't even run because i made sure it prints out the value of the downloaded URL after it is done, but i see nothing in my debug console, where am going wrong here?

i keep getting this error `No object exists at the desired reference.`

by the way, the `"thesnapshot.data()['image']"` in my code is equal to the name of the image file e.g `books.jpg` which is the exact name of the file and it is in a folder called category as you can see below,  would really appreciate some enlightenment on this, thanks

```
class Home extends State<HomeScreen> {
  var url;
  ListView.builder(shrinkWrap: true, padding: EdgeInsets.all(0), physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length, itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) 
    {
        DocumentSnapshot thesnapshot = snapshot.data.docs[index];
        current_category = thesnapshot.data()['category'];
        printUrl() async {
            Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("category/" + thesnapshot.data()['image'].toString());
            var togo = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
            setState(() {
            url =  togo;
            print(url);
        });
    
}

printUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the .ref() included in your reference doesn't go thereas well as the thesnapshot.data()['image'].toString().

Try something like this

```
Future<void> downloadURLExample() async {
  String downloadURL = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref('users/123/avatar.jpg')
      .getDownloadURL();
```

Extracted from the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage)