# Firebase storage error "No object exists at the desired reference and no auth token for request"

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

i keep getting this error  when i try to get the download URL for my files in my firebase storage, I don't  know what the problem is anymore, I have tried a lot of things

```
    Exception has occurred.
FirebaseException ([firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.)

W/StorageUtil(32618): no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest(32618): no auth token for request
E/StorageException(32618): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(32618): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(32618):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
```

here are my storage rules

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
```

here is my code

```
 return   GridView.builder(
                
    shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisSpacing: 20, 
    mainAxisSpacing: 20,
    childAspectRatio: 1.7,
      crossAxisCount:2),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

    checkItems =  FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('items');

checkItems = checkItems..where('id',isEqualTo: user_id.toString()); 

    DocumentSnapshot thesnapshot = snapshot.data.docs[index]; 


    
                                                              printUrl() async {
    Reference ref = 
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('antivirus.jpg');
       
       var togo = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
    setState(() {
      url =  togo;
    print('here is your url duuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuudreeeeeeeeee'+url);
    });
    
}

printUrl()
```

.....................................................................................................................................

Comment: Can you: 1) update the code to log the value of `thesnapshot.data()['image'].toString()`? 2) include the updated code and its output in your question?

Comment: i updated my code, the value of thesnapshot.data()['image'] was 'antvirus.jpg' , i saved this file in my cloud firestore database

Comment: it gives me the same error i wrote at the beginning of my code

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64966923/failing-to-get-a-download-url-from-firebase-storageno-object-exists-at-the-desi) btw?

Comment: What specific line in the code gives you the error?

Comment: this line " Reference ref = 
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('antivirus.jpg');: it says the object doesn't exist at location and no auth token for request

Comment: That line doesn't communicate with the Firebase servers yet, so it can't be throwing the error. My best bet in that case is that it's the `ref.getDownloadURL()` right after it, which really means that no file exists in the location in the bucket that you're pointing at. I recommend checking your configuration data (are you looking at the right bucket/project) and the spelling of filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i fixed removing the extension from the method, try like this:

```
 Reference ref = 
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('antivirus');
```

it worked for me.