# firebase_storage/object-not-found No object exists at the desired reference

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

my code

```
Future<String> uploadFile(File _image) async {
  int uploadTimestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('posts/$uploadTimestamp');
  UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_image);
  final TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
  final url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

  return url;
}
```

- firebase_storage: ^10.3.1
- firebase_core: ^1.19.1

**Error: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.**

Comment: Hello! It's a good practice here on Stack Overflow to follow [these rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) after somebody answers any of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the

```
await ref.putFile(_image);
```

before the:

```
final TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
```

And then call:

```
await ref.getDownloadURL();
```

after the upload in order to get the download url.

and also try to listen to the different upload states like:

```
uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
  switch (taskSnapshot.state) {
    case TaskState.running:
      final progress =
          100.0 * (taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred / taskSnapshot.totalBytes);
      print("Upload is $progress% complete.");
      break;
    case TaskState.paused:
      print("Upload is paused.");
      break;
    case TaskState.canceled:
      print("Upload was canceled");
      break;
    case TaskState.error:
      // Handle unsuccessful uploads
      break;
    case TaskState.success:
      // Handle successful uploads on complete
      // ...
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: sorry skipped a line ` UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_image);` updated the question

Answer (score 1):

basically this error shows because you don't have started your storage at firebase console, you should first go to storage and press get started, then set your rules for test mode in case you are using for testing and after that full restart your app, hope it works for you.

> firebase_storage/object-not-found No object exists at the desired
> reference

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to achieve. one suspeect here is youre not calling _image anywhere. Seem like youre trying to upload an int.

Comment: updated the code trying to upload an image to firestore

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful. I put in together this.

```
Future<String> uploadImageToDefaultBucket(File image) async {
    Reference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref("your-ref").child("your-path");
    UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(image);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask;
    return taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided is generally caused by an [incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64971179/16929894) Cloud Storage bucket URL. The image you would like to retrieve cannot be located in your Cloud Storage. You should first check that the bucket URL and file name are correctly spelled.

Additionally, [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files#upload_files) is how you add the image extension.